# Building a Camera that tracks a target

Tags: camera, wireless

I am planning to build a camera which will track a target and keep "looking at it" in motion. The camera needs to have vertical/horizontal panning/tilt.

I am not sure if this is the platform to discuss this. I would appreciate if this can be broken down into smaller tasks / units

[Update]

Thanks Kenneth & Clement. I broke down the problem into smaller bits
Hardware interfacing
1) slider motor -- for movement along a track, 
2) pan & tilt motor to move in horizontal & vertically.
3) wifi unit to connect to the device remotely 
4) control device using an ipad / joystick + visual display

Programming required -
1) identify target and camera always on that - use IR locking (once at start & once at end) and keep the camera looking at it always. Not very clever!

2) use openCV to identify target & use it to 'keep looking' at it - light can be an issue if we are to look at target in low-light conditions

3) smoothing algorithm to avoid sharp movements

4) develop app for ios

Answer (score 2):

I would break this down to the following steps:

- sourcing a pan/tilt module (with servos).
- working out how to drive the servos so the pan/tilt operates as needed:

  - direction.
  - speed.
- working out how to identify an object from the cameras stream/image.
- working out how to identify the object has moved (and which direction).
- integrating it all together.

Breaking it down like this also allows you to switch to another task if you get stuck on something - give yourself some thinking space...

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Kennet has mentioned I would suggest:

- Rotate the camera module with servo/stepper motor w/ rotating base [you might have some luck here](http://www.swanrobotics.com/projects/diy-pan-tilt-camera/)
- [Adafruit has a nice tutorial on controlling servos using python](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-8-using-a-servo-motor/overview)
- As for the Computer Vision aspect of your project, I think open electronics has a nice [tutorial](http://www.open-electronics.org/computer-vision-with-raspberry-pi-and-the-camera-pi-module/) to get you started.
- Since you will already be using python for both the servo control and image analysis, it should be relatively easy to tie the 2 together.  e.g. If you're object moves off the centre of the camera (0,0) rotate your server by that offset.

Anyways, best of luck with your project and have fun!